# Temporarily disable BufWrite script in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have vim setup to run Autoformat when I write to files but periodically forget to add an extension to my blacklist before making edits to it. Now I can't save the edits since the autoformating messes up the indentation. Is there a way of saving without running the BufWrite scripts?

The line in my vimrc is:

`au BufWrite * if index(blacklist, &ft) < 0 | :Autoformat`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three options:

```
:noa[utocmd] w[rite]
```

will perform a save without triggering *any* autocmds. As long as you don't have any other customizations / plugins using autocmds, that would be fine.

```
:set eventignore=BufWrite | write | set eventignore=
```

will temporarily turn off just the `BufWrite` event.

Alternatively, you could also add a conditional around your autocmd:

```
au BufWrite * if ! exists('g:no_autoformat') && index(blacklist, &ft) < 0 | :Autoformat
```

That would enable you to selectively disable just that particular autocmd via `:let g:no_autoformat = 1`.

<sup>PS: Your `:autocmd` is missing the closing `| endif`.</sup>